# How to fetch only matched items of a php array from mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my array in php: *$list = array('dog', 'tiger', 'lion', 'elephant')*

**Table name:** *watchlist*   **Database:** *assignment*
[image]

After comparing the ***$list*** with the ***watchlist*** table it should print only the matched items. 
So, the output for this will be:
*dog
tiger*

Is there any mysql query to get this output. I am weak in mysql. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM watchlist WHERE name IN ('dog', 'tiger', 'lion', 'elephant')`. Of course you would want to bind the values and stuff like that, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: SQL has IN operator... `name IN('dog', 'tiger', 'lion', 'elephant')`  will give the results you need.. if you also need/want to enforce the order you need to add `ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'dog', 'tiger', 'lion', 'elephant')` this is a MySQL only function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `watchlist` WHERE `assignment` IN('".implode("','",$list)."')";
```

> Note: Make sure that any external input is sanitized.

Comment: I feel the next question coming.. How to sanitize.. stackoverflow is meant to solve questions not to generate new question.